# MAILKIT change message.From

Tags: vb.net, mailkit

I need to change in the message (smtpClient object) the

```
"message.From.Add(New MailboxAddress(sendername, senderemail)"
```

already prepared with another function to

```
"message.From.Add(New MailboxAddress(sendername, othersenderemail)"
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What seems to be the difficulty? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that what you are trying to ask is how to send an email from `myaccount@example.com` but have the From header be `no-reply@example.com` (or some such).

You have 2 options:

1. You can set the `message.Sender` to the address you *actually* want to send from while setting the `message.From` to the address you want the message to appear to be from. This has the side-effect of adding a `Sender: My Name <myaccount@example.com>` header in the message which may or may not be something you care about.
2. You can use the `SmtpClient.Send(MimeMessage message, MailboxAddress sender, IEnumerable<MailboxAddress> recipeints, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` API which will not change the headers of the MimeMessage.

For example:

```
var message = new MimeMessage ();
message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress (string.Empty, "no-reply@mycompany.com"));
message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Customer Name", "customer@example.com"));
message.Subject = "Your order is on its way!";
message.Body = GenerateMessageBody ();

using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("smtp.mycompany.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    client.Authenticate ("myaccount@mycompany.com", "password");

    var sender = new MailboxAddress (string.Empty, "myaccount@mycompany.com");

    // This API is new in MimeKit v3.0, but will collect the unique email 
    // addresses in the To, Cc, and Bcc fields into 1 collection.
    var recipients = message.GetRecipients (true);

    // Send the message from your account w/o having to modify the From header.
    client.Send (message, sender, recipients);

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

Comment: You can accept my answer by click the checkbox next to the top of my answer and upvote it

Comment: So soooooorryyyyy, I forgot this